# Alternative Way of Declaring AndroidX Libraries

Tags: android, dependencies, androidx

I have seen some Kotlin DSL repos just declare `Androidx` Artifacts with this simple format.

```
dependencies {

    implementation(AndroidX.core.ktx)
    implementation(AndroidX.compose.ui)

... }
```

However, this alternative way is not being resolved in my case.
[image]

I'm using Kotlin DSL for my gradle.build files but I'm not sure what I am missing in my set-up.

Comment: Did you set up a version catalog, in Kotlin or TOML? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Comment: I hadn't created a `VersionCatalog` before. I have now created it and the dependencies are being resolved. What I now don't understand is what the catalog has to do with `Androidx` Libraries since I don't see any `AndroidX` property or object on the [TOML file](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/BMIPro/blob/master/gradle/libs.versions.toml)

Comment: Your TOML file link leads to a 404. If you edit your question to include the TOML content, perhaps we can point out the connection!